# Data from my class is null?

Tags: java, class, object, null

I have a class holding a `boolean`, and two `doubles`, and then an `array` of that class, I need the `boolean` and `doubles` to have defaults values of `false, 0.0, and 0.0`, and then I have `function` that refers to an element of the `array` and the moment I try to access an one of the variables from the class it throws an exception saying its null. Here is my class and my function calling it.

```
    public class PanelData {
        boolean flag = false;
        double tempStart = 0.0;
        double tempEnd = 0.0;
    }

    private PanelData[] panelInfo = new PanelData[115];

private void panelInfoHandler (int i, double timeStart, double timeEnd) throws SQLException
    {
        if (!panelInfo[i].flag) {
            delete();
            insert();
            panelInfo[i].flag = true;
            panelInfo[i].tempStart = timeStart;
            panelInfo[i].tempEnd = timeEnd;
        }
        else if (panelInfo[i].tempStart <= timeStart && panelInfo[i].tempEnd >= timeEnd) {

        }
        else
        {
            insert();
            panelInfo[i].tempStart = timeStart;
            panelInfo[i].tempEnd = timeEnd;
        }
    }
```

here is how I call the class.

```
panelInfoHandler(9, parsedStart, parsedEnd);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new PanelData[115]` creates an array of `115` null references. Have you populated `panelInfo` with references to actual objects?

At a minimum, you then need to loop through that array and create new instances of `PanelData` for each element in the array, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < panelInfo.length; i++)
  panelInfo[i] = new PanelData();
```

Comment: oh no I haven't, should I use an `ArrayList` instead and then run through a `for loop` adding the the references to the actual object?

Comment: @Beef: If the size of the collection needs to change at runtime, then working with `ArrayList` might indeed be easier.

Comment: @Beef - So do you already have the objects instantiated, or did you intend to create new ones?

Comment: I have it all working now, thanks for the input, I already know how many objects I will need though so either aix, pedros, or hughs answer worked as a quick fix, thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Your array is full of `null` elements until you initialize it.  To clarify, if you create an array of primitive objects, you get an array of default (i.e. 0) values.  However, an array of `Object`s gets created with `null` elements.

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[10];  // 10 default values of 0
Integer[] myIntegerArray = new Integer[10];  // 10 null elements
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line and then assign the values:

```
 if(panelInfo[i] == null) panelInfo[i] = new PanelInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like

```
for(int i=0;i<115; i++)
{
   PanelInfo[i] = new PanelData();
}
```

(Or whatever is the correct Java Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class PanelData {
        boolean flag = false;
        double tempStart;
        double tempEnd;

        public PanelData() {
            flag = false;
            tempStart = 0.0;
            tempEnd = 0.0;    
    }
    private PanelData[] panelInfo = new PanelData[115]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 115; i++)
       panelInfo[i] = new PanelData();
```

Creating the default constructor lets you instantiate the variables with the default values (false, 0.0, 0.0) in this case so you can test if you are getting a vanilla object back or not.